# Some high version OPPO and VIVO system can't open debug apk?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run debug app from Android Studio, I can install app but can't run app, When I'm open app it crashed.

Some one say use gradle < 2.3.0 version is run well.

Somebody know the reason?

Comment: please post your exception log

Comment: You can't run debug app in different device if you're using the apk produced after you clicking Run. You need to build the apk then you can use the apk to other devices.

Answer (score 2):

follow settings you can run debug app on oppo and vivo

**1. Disable Instant Run**

[image]

**2. Add gradle.properties Settings**

```
android.injected.testOnly=false
```

[image]